# How to upload a photo using Sonata Media Bundle

Tags: symfony

I am trying to upload an image using Sonata Media Bundle.

This is my form in twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

                        {{ form_widget(form.imagine) }}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

                        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

And the code in controller

```
$data = array();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('imagine','sonata_media_type',array('provider'=>'sonata.media.provider.image'))
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            $data = $form->getData();
            echo '<pre>';
            \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($data);
            exit;
            echo '</pre>';
        }

        return $this->render('MedAppBundle:Profile:change_picture.html.twig',array(
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ));
```

When I open the browser it shows this :

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3p1E.png)

Now what should I  set in order NOT to show me : No media link to the object and Information.

And then what do I need to do to upload the photo?

Thank you!